# Deezer API : DZ.getLoginStatus returned 'connected' even if the user has logged out from deezer

Tags: api, deezer

I need to know if a user is connected to Deezer. How can I know if a user is logged in to Deezer and will be able to hear more than 30sec of a track ?

I think that DZ.getLoginStatus method return connected because it's about the connection to my app, it is right ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you have to use DZ.getLoginStatus() which returns you the connection status of the user to Deezer, and so your app. If the method returns a 'connected' status, it means that the user will be allowed to play more than 30s.

Comment: But, when a user log in to my app, and after requesting for Deezer authorization, I get the token with a 'connected' status. After that, I'm going to Deezer and I log out from Deezer. Then, refresh my app page: I still have the 'connected' status, but I'm not allowed to play more than 30s. What is the problem ?